# Running nautilus through Xming opens 2 windows

Tags: desktop-environment, nautilus

I'm trying to use `PuTTY` and `Xming` to forward `nautilus` to my Windows machine.

So everything is set, I run `nautilus` command from the `PuTTY` window, then I get 2 nautilus windows.  one is titled "root - File Browser", the other one titled "x-nautilus-desktop" which looks very much like the Gnome desktop without the taskbars and menus.   And the later one cannot be closed, I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it.

This gets me very much confused. What I expected is just a file browser.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does `nautilus --no-desktop` or `nautilus --no-desktop --browser` do the trick?

Comment: @steeldriver --no-desktop works, thank you. But what is happening here?